# How can I disable my submit button when a text area is left blank?

Tags: html, typescript, vue.js, tailwind-css

I am trying to make a submit button that is disabled when a text area is left blank, but alas I am not seeing results. If any advice could be spared it would be greatly appreciated. Here is the code that pertains to this problem. This submit button works as if it were not disabled, so I'm guessing there must be something wrong in my typescript or the way that I am constructing the disable in the first place, but I am getting to the point where I am running out of Ideas. If anyone has any questions feel free to ask.

```
<template>
  <div id="editEntryDiv">
    <div id="mainContent" v-if="loaded">
      <PartsForm v-model="localPartEntry" />
    </div>

    <Teleport to="#mainContent">
      <div class="actionBar">
        <!-- Empty Div Required for formatting -->
        <div>
          <button id="deleteButton" @click="deleteItem(parseInt(id))">
            <i class="fas fa-trash"></i>
            <span>Delete</span>
          </button>
        </div>

        <!-- Empty Div Required for formatting -->
        <div>
          <button
            id="submitButton"
            :class="{ disabled: localPartEntry.partNumber == undefined }"
            :disabled="localPartEntry.partNumber == undefined"
            @click="submitItem"
          >
            <i class="fas fa-paper-plane"></i>
            <span>Submit</span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Teleport>
  </div>
</template>
```

here is the typescript:

```
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
import { usePartStore } from "../stores/part-store";
import PartsForm from "../components/PartsForm.vue";
import { PartDefinition } from "../types/PartDefinition";
import { mapStores } from 'pinia'
export default defineComponent({
  components: {
    PartsForm,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      loaded: false,
      localPartEntry: {} as PartDefinition,
    };
  },
  watch: {
    localPartEntry: {
      handler() {
        if (!this.loaded) return
        sessionStorage.setItem("unsavedPart", JSON.stringify(this.localPartEntry))
      },
      deep: true
    }
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapStores(usePartStore),
    id(): string {
      return this.$route.params.id.toString();
    },
  },
  methods: {
    async submitItem(): Promise<void> {
      this.localPartEntry.id = parseInt(this.id);
      if (await this.partStore.editPartDefinition(this.localPartEntry))
        if (await this.partStore.getParts())
          this.$router.push({
            path: `/`,
          });
    },
    async deleteItem(id: number) {
      if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this entry?"))
        if (await this.partStore.deletePartDefinition(id))
          if (await this.partStore.getParts())
            this.$router.push({
              path: `/`,
            });
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    for (let element of this.partStore.partEntries as PartDefinition[]) {
      if (element.id == parseInt(this.$route.params.id.toString())) {
        this.localPartEntry.id = element.id;
        this.localPartEntry.partNumber = element.partNumber;
        this.localPartEntry.variant = element.variant;
        this.localPartEntry.revision = element.revision;
        this.localPartEntry.description = element.description;
        this.localPartEntry.supplier = element.supplier;
        this.localPartEntry.previewImagePath = element.previewImagePath;
        this.localPartEntry.previewImageDateTime = element.previewImageDateTime;
        this.localPartEntry.obsolete = element.obsolete;
        this.localPartEntry.internalOnly = element.internalOnly;

        this.loaded = true;
        break;
      }
    }
  },
});
</script>
```

And finally, the css:

```
<style lang="sass" scoped>

#editEntryDiv
  width: 100%
  height: 100%
  background: $primary-background

  display: flex
  flex-direction: column
  overflow-y: auto

  -ms-overflow-style: none // for Internet Explorer, Edge */
  scrollbar-width: none // for Firefox */

  &::-webkit-scrollbar
    display: none // for Chrome, Safari, and Opera */

#mainContent
  margin-top: 1rem
  margin-bottom: 5rem
  flex-grow: 1

#submitButton
  border: 1px solid $primary-accent-color
  font-size: 1.5rem
  border-radius: .25rem
  cursor: pointer
  padding: .25rem .75rem
  transition: background .3s, color .3s
  color: $primary-accent-color
  background: transparent

  display: flex
  flex-direction: row
  justify-content: center
  align-items: center
  gap: .5rem

  &:hover
    color: $tertiary-background
    background: $primary-accent-color
.disabled
  background: grey !important
#deleteButton
  border: 1px solid $primary-accent-color
  font-size: 1.5rem
  border-radius: .25rem
  cursor: pointer
  padding: .25rem .75rem
  transition: background .3s, color .3s
  color: $primary-accent-color
  background: transparent

  display: flex
  flex-direction: row
  justify-content: center
  align-items: center
  gap: .5rem

  &:hover
    color: $tertiary-background
    background: $primary-accent-color
.actionBar
  width: 100%
  min-height: 4rem !important
  background: $secondary-background

  display: flex
  justify-content: space-between

  position: fixed
  bottom: 0px
  right: 0px

  &>div
    display: flex
    flex-direction: row
    align-items: center
    gap: 1rem
    margin: 0 1rem
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just check with [Logical NOT (!)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_NOT) operator which takes truth to falsity and vice versa. Hence, If there will be no value in the textarea it will return `false` else `true`.

**Working Demo :**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    content: ''
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  Textarea content: {{ content }}
  <br><br>
  <textarea v-model="content"></textarea>
  <button id="submitButton" :disabled="!content.trim()">
    <span>Submit</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

I just added an example to show you how to achieve. You can made the changes in your original code.